# PyCapture2 DLL Load Failed

Tags: python

I'm trying to get PyCapture2 working and I get this error when importing

```
>>> import flycapture2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\flycapture2.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\flycapture2.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have been trying everything to find the source of this error. 
I have reinstalled Anaconda, I have made sure that the FlyCapture2 SDK is installed correctly, I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

I was also pulling my hair out for days trying to sort this very issue out. I "solved" it by abandoning PyCapture2 altogether and opting for the **Spinnaker** library. It's probably the better choice anyway, since Spinnaker SDK has superceded the FlyCapture2 SDK and there is no guarantee of compatibility between future cameras manufactured by FLIR Systems and the now obsolte FlyCapture2 SDK.

You can get the Spinnaker SDK from [here](https://www.ptgrey.com/spinnaker-sdk). You will need to sign up to FLIR systems, but it's free to do so.

Spinnaker SDK is written for a bunch of languages. The Python version feels a *little* bit like an afterthought - the example code isn't particularly helpful. But you can find quite a nice repository of python Spinnaker examples collated by a team called Soc-Cog [here](https://github.com/SocCog-Team/Multiple-Cameras-Acquisition).